# Flutter for Android without setting android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I have had some issues getting requests from the Android emulator to interact with FireBase. I ended up setting:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in the manifest file.

A quick search tells me that this allows insecure connections:

```
Android 6.0 introduced the `useCleartextTraffic` attribute under the application element in the android manifest. The default value in Android P is “false”. Setting this to true indicates that the app intends to use clear network traffic
```

What do I have to do in order to deploy my application without setting `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`?

Comment: If you need to use a HTTP (not HTTPS) connection, then you will need to set android:usesClearTextTraffic="true"

Comment: So you shall check your code to see the protocol on every HTTP requests. If you find one using "http://" instead of "https://", then you shall change it to the "s" one if feasible.

Comment: And if you find any request fails to call after your change, if you have the ability to contact the server side to change for you, just go for it. Else you will need to do the final step, set usesCleartextTraffic to true and allow the connection of that particular HTTP request allowed to be sniffed. (e.g., Network monitor tools in Android Studio or Google Play Store, Wireshark on your PC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

In the `res/xml/` folder create a `network_config.xml` file that contains the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I believe that `10.0.0.2` is the ip address that the emulator uses on the Android device. If I am wrong, you can update the ip address to whatever might be the correct address.

Then in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the application tag add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"`. The output would look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This should allow any traffic coming from an emulator be allowed in clear text, but block other endpoints from being accessed over http/cleartext.

## Option 2

You could hypothetically configure a setup with gradle to release a different manifest for debug and release builds. I just looked at the android folder for flutter and what you could do instead is go to the ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml and add the following:

```xml
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

Your output `AndroidManifest.xml` in the debug folder (which should only be applied to debug builds, may look something similar to this:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your.package">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <!-- ADD FROM HERE-->
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    </application>
    <!-- TO HERE-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

### Note

I haven't tested option 2 myself, but from my understanding, this *should* work. This [medium article](https://lorenzoromagnoni.medium.com/how-to-have-different-values-in-androidmanifest-xml-and-info-plist-based-on-flutter-build-type-5c6c596fc0c6) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both option 1 and option 2 are ways to enable communication in clear text.

The reason behind the original question is that I would like to have encrypted communication. But I am starting to think that this clear text traffic thingy is required while developing the app? And to clarify. I want the end result to communicate trough a encrypted connection which I now am wondering will work on a real system?

Comment: Option 1 sends clear text only to the debugging ip address on an android device, never to an actual service. Option 2 sends clear text only on debug builds, it should not send it on a release build which you would send to production. Clear text is required when communicating with the emulators locally since you do not have a certificate on the emulated service. Option 2 is more akin to running if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {...} in Android than Option 1. Option 1 is sending traffic to 10.0.2.2 which is the special IP address to connect to the 'localhost' of the host computer from an Android emulator.